# Jenkins doesn't stop after Git clone

Tags: git, github, jenkins

We are setting up a Jenkins server, and are trying to configure our first project.

The first step was to clone the private repository from GitHub, which now apparently works. At least we don't get any SSH errors any longer, mainly thanks to [this article](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/jenkins-git-clone-via-ssh-on-windows-7-x64).

Now we have not yet configured and build steps or post-build steps, but we would assume Jenkins to clone the git repository, and then stop (with success).

Unfortunately, this is *NOT* what happens. Instead Jenkins just keeps working and working and working, infinitely … when you cancel the job and take a look at the log file, everything looks fine, except for the note that the user cancelled the job.

This is the log:

```
Started by user John Doe
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\FooProject
Checkout:FooProject / C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\FooProject - …
  … hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1daf314
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Build was aborted
Aborted by John Doe
Finished: ABORTED
```

We are using Git 1.8.4, run on Windows, and use the `git.exe` file (as the `gitk.cmd` did not work, but raised an error about leaking a child process).

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: It's just stalled at the clone? In my experience, that normally means git.exe is waiting for input. If you haven't done so, try running the Jenkins service as a normal user (not LOCAL SERVICE or NETWORK SERVICE), and then log as the same user on the server and attempt to clone the repository. Then you can solve any issues you're having with the clone interactively.

Comment: I don't know whether it's *AT* cloning or *AFTER* cloning. But I've added the log output, so maybe this helps.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion - can you give me a hint how to run git.exe from command-line with SSH on Windows? If it was OSX or Linux I'd knew ... :-/

Comment: You'll need to emulate the exact way Jenkins is doing it. So take the Git executable path you provided to Jenkins (probably `C:\Git\cmd\git.exe` if you followed the article). Then use that path in Command Prompt (or `cmd`, they are the same thing) from the start menu and run `C:\Git\cmd\git.exe clone [git repo path here]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, we've found the issue: In the system-wide environment variables there is a variable called `GIT_SSL`, which pointed to TortoiseSVN's `plink.exe` which was obviously wrong.

Once we changed that to the `ssh.exe` provided by MSysGit, everything works as expected :-)